# autoloader works for files in root but not for files in subfolders

Tags: php

I have an autoloader in a file called config.php as follows:

```html
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    require $fileName;
});
```

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

The blacked out folder is the project's name.  Notice that config.php is located in the "includes" subfolder.  It autoloads classes just fine for index.php by including the line `require_once ('includes/config.php');` in the script.  A new file, functions.php, was created to handle communications with the database for AJAX requests.  The autoloader works fine for this file so long as it is in the project root and `require_once ('includes/config.php');` is included in the script.  However, when functions.php gets moved to a subfolder, say the js subfolder, and `require_once ('../includes/config.php');` is included in the script, the autoloader does not work.  The error message displayed is **Warning: require(classes\model\Operation.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxx\OOP\includes\config.php on line 74**.  Why isn't the autoloader working when functions.php is in a subfolder?  I would like it to work for files in the project root AND for files in subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with for this problem:

1. In the includes/config.php file, updated autoloader to PSR-4, see Closure Example here: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md.  The anonymous function has a variable called $base_dir.
2. Created a file called root.php and stored it in project root (same location as index.php).  It contains the following:

```html
<?php
# capture project's root directory
// config.php, which is stored in a subfolder, requires this file so it knows this information
// purpose of concatenating DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is to add a slash to end of path
$root = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
?>
```

3. In includes/config.php, defined ROOT constant as follows:

```html
<?php
require (__DIR__ . '/../root.php');  // get project's root directory from file stored in root - this is needed to have access to the $root variable to create the ROOT constant in this script
define ('ROOT', $root);    // this constant is used when in a file stored in a subfolder requires files stored in other subfolders
?>
```

4. In the autoloader, located in includes/config.php, set $base_dir as follows: `$base_dir = ROOT . 'classes/';`.
5. In js/functions.php included config file: `require_once (__DIR__ . '/../includes/config.php');`

Now the autoloader works for index.php, stored in the root directory, and for functions.php, stored in the js subfolder.